# Use Stack Overflow to measure hot languages

Tags: discussion, languages, popularity

Is it possible to see which tags were the fastest growing in a certain period, say 2011?

I see that C# is the most popular tag on Stack Overflow, but wondered if there were any tags that have come from nowhere this year. I suspect F# grew a lot, but I would be interested to see if that is quantifiable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just keep in mind that a tag's popularity on SO does not necessarily have any correlation with a language's popularity in the real world (which is, itself, a score that could be measured in numerous different ways).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See the great [Stack Exchange stats](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/) by [Greg Hewgill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill), [example](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/?c%23+java):

[image: h]

Answer (score 1):

Using Tomasz's answer as a starting point, [here is a graph](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/#!java+c+c%2B%2B+python+c%23+r+php+javascript+ruby+vb.net+perl) showing StackOverflow usage trends of some of the most popular languages as appearing amongst the top of the [TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) and [IEEE spectrum rankings](http://spectrum.ieee.org/static/interactive-the-top-programming-languages-2016) at the time of writing:

[image: Tag activity per week since 2008]